# Using hook_user_format_name_alter(), how to change username on user paths?

Tags: 8, users, hooks

I am using `hook_user_format_name_alter()` to change the way usernames are displayed through my site.

However, on the user paths:

- user/UID
- user/UID/edit

The page title is set to the **username**, not the result of `hook_user_format_name_alter()`.

Is there an easy way to override the username here (and preferably anywhere else) and replace it with `hook_user_format_name_alter()`?

My goto solution would be the [Real Name](https://www.drupal.org/project/realname) module, but I ran into [a bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2910304) so I'm trying to do this programatically myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the title callback you have in core for /user/UID:

*UserController::userTitle*

```
/**
   * Route title callback.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\user\UserInterface $user
   *   The user account.
   *
   * @return string|array
   *   The user account name as a render array or an empty string if $user is
   *   NULL.
   */
  public function userTitle(UserInterface $user = NULL) {
    return $user ? ['#markup' => $user->getUsername(), '#allowed_tags' => Xss::getHtmlTagList()] : '';
  }
```

Unfortunately this uses the method `getUsername()`, which doesn't invoke hook_user_format_name_alter().

You need a custom title callback, where you get the username with the method `$user->getDisplayName()`, which does invoke the hook.

Then change the title callback in the user route `entity.user.canonical`:

```
$route->setDefault('_title_callback', '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyController::userTitle');
```

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones.

---

Had the feeling this can't be right and searched for an issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2648420. This is committed for D8.5. Until then you can apply the patch, which simply replaces getUserName() with getDisplayName() in UserController.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2648420 is NOT committed

Comment: It was marked a duplicate of [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2629286).